# What's the composition of Ceres?

Tags: asteroids, ceres

Strangely, there isn't a lot of information on Ceres on the internet. I want to know the specific percentages of its composition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @JamesK pointed out.   We don't know it's specific composition.   Nasa did a fly-by recently, but nothing has ever landed on Ceres.   Estimates can be made, but it's hard to know specifically what the inside of a planet is made of.   We don't even know the interior of the Earth all that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are not known for certain, however it is generally thought to have a rocky core, formed of silicates (aluminium and magnesium silicate for example) and a large mantle of water ice, perhaps 50% by volume, 25% by mass. The surface crust is formed of various carbonaceous and iron minerals: siderite, dolomite, cronstedtite. There may be a small iron core.

Comment: Any chance of giving  source?